# client side click event instead of code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

How can I make this run at server?

```
javascript:
function confirm_delete()
{
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")==true)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

asp

```
div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm_delete();");
```

Comment: it doesnt run at server tho? Maybe I worded it wrong.

Comment: no javascript runs on the client only.

Comment: do a response.write('<script>') on the server side, quick and dirty fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture an event at the server side, you need to use `runat="server"`:

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:Button id="button1" Text="Click me!" runat="server" OnClick="confirm_delete" />
</form>
```

The event handler itself needs to be in the code behind.  I don't remember if JScript is supported in ASP.net but `confirm` definitely isn't.

To have this run on the server, you would want to refactor your application.  You would need the `confirm_delete` function to render the page with a form that confirms their action.  This isn't so bad because you can have it there already just hidden.  `confirm_delete` would hide the normal content and show the confirmation form.  The confirmation form would need to have "OK" or cancel buttons, also hooked to back end event handlers that either execute the deletion (I assume this is where the server `OnClick` is already wired) or take you back to the full page view.

It's much more complex than a JavaScript confirm popup but its not too awful to do.